# Dispatch outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to dispatch outside component. I want to use option 2 from this link [https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/][1]. My code look like this

```
const loginUser = async (data) => {
    return axios.get(url + "/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then(() => {
        axios.post(url + '/api/login', data)
            .then(res => {
                return res.data

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);

            })
    })
}
export const handleLogin = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('test');
    try {
        const user = await loginUser(data);
        dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

And into my component

```
    const test = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault;
        handleLogin({email: 'test@test.pl', password: 'password'})
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(test)}>
//...
```

It doesn't finish code and it may contain mistakes but currently the most important for me is why this code doesn't work and if sometimes is wrong why doesn't show any error. I think that problem is in *sync(dispatch)*. In this example I add console.log for test and it wasn't display. Without that function display console.log.
Redux thunk is added to the store too

```
const store = createStore(allReducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading, you clearly want to dispatch from within a react component.

Answer (score 1):

import store and use like this :

```
  store.dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
```

and you can get state out of component with :

```
store.getState().items
```

Comment: I doesn't want to import store. I want to use this method which i show ib my post. I used that but in other places not and I want to know why.

Comment: I answer you in other post .

Answer (score 0):

you did not dispatch your actions in your component and in your action js .
you can call an action in component by props and dispatch and I could not see the props so I use useDispatch and call handleLogin action there.

use this in action.js file:

```
 const user = await loginUser(data)(dispatch);
```

instead :

```
   const user = await loginUser(data);
```

then in component:

```
   import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
    

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const test = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault;
        dispatch(handleLogin({email: 'test@test.pl', password: 'password'}))
    }
```

Comment: Look that after submit nothink work, console.log and so on.

Comment: I edited my answer ,check it again